# Oracle temporary storage

Tags: sql-server, oracle, temporary-objects

I need to execute a one shot script (that is, it will not be deployed in a living system) to correct some values in existing tables.

The script itself is not relevant. The problem here is the "some values" part: the data to be adjusted (keys and old and new values) was collected on a spreadsheet. Say it has many many rows and like 4 or 5 columns.

In MSSQL Server lingo I would create a temporary table to hold the input values and input them all after exporting the spreadsheet to CSV (plus some textual transformations, perhaps using sed(1) or paste(1) unix shell commands):

```
CREATE TABLE #inputdata (col1 AS INTEGER, col2 AS VARCHAR ...);

INSERT INTO #inputdata VALUES (...);
...
INSERT INTO #inputdata VALUES (...);

-- then comes the script which can SELECT FROM #inputdata
-- just like a normal table
```

I need to do this in Oracle.

Oracle temporary tables seem to be only data-wise temporary, I mean, they should already exist in the database before being used. I don't have, and I'll never have the necessary permissions to create it; SQLServer allows temporary table creation regardless of ordinary table creation permissions.

Any ideas?

Comment: What privileges do you have?  If you don't have permission to create objects, then using either a temporary table or an external table would be out.  If you can't get privileges to create any sort of object in any schema, you could possibly use a PL/SQL collection but then you'd need to do a bit of work to initialize the collection based on the data in your file.

Comment: In oracle you have arrays of your table types, etc. In pl/sql there are many ways to store temp data. If you have create permissions to your schema, you can do `create table xxx as select ....`. http://ss64.com/oraplsql/declaretbl.html

Comment: The only privileges I have are INSERT/SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE. And nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the issue with the WITH clause:

```
WITH inputdata AS (
    SELECT  ... AS col1, ... AS col2, ... FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT  ... AS col1, ... AS col2, ... FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT  ... AS col1, ... AS col2, ... FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT  ... AS col1, ... AS col2, ... FROM DUAL
)
SELECT ...
FROM .... INNER JOIN inputdata ON ...
WHERE inputdata...
```

In my script, only SELECTs and INSERTs were involved.

For INSERTs the syntax becomes:

```
INSERT INTO tableX (...)
WITH inputdata AS (
    SELECT  ... AS col1, ... AS col2, ... FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT  ... AS col1, ... AS col2, ... FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT  ... AS col1, ... AS col2, ... FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT  ... AS col1, ... AS col2, ... FROM DUAL
)
SELECT ...
FROM .... INNER JOIN inputdata ON ...
WHERE inputdata...
```

Comment: An horrible solution, in my opinion, but did work. Don't know whether the WITH clause would work on UPDATEs or DELETEs (for DELETE I think a subquery resolves all cases; for UPDATE, I can't think of a solution for the case when the value to be updated comes from inputtable).